# Filtering for Unique Values with different ID Numbers

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to filter for unique values from one tab to another. However in both tabs, I have an ID Column. I basically want to align the Unique values to their respective ID Number, then use the filter view to hide the blanks.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

I used this formula:

```
={"PO#","MP#";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4:A,'SHEET1'!A5:H,{7,8},0)))}
```

and came up with this:

```
​={"PO#","MP#";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4:A,FILTER('SHEET1'!A5:H,UNIQUE('SHEET1'!G5:G)),{7,8},0)))}​
```

PO# and MP# in the second tab are the values with duplicates and will be imported from SHEET1's Column G and H respectively. Both tab's ID Column are in Column A (They just start in different positions).

I expected the rows with duplicated PO# and MP# to be blank, until the next unique row.
I have also linked a Google Sheets [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12HLROh6H_KC5HlJZPCMS3GjNHAcnSmxBHT1a5QUEnAY/edit?usp=sharing) to illustrate my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe enter the desired output manually so that it becomes more clear on what you are envisioning to achieve and all?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `vlookup()` and `unique()`, like this:

```
={ Sheet1!A1:A }
```

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A1:A, 
      vlookup( 
        unique(Sheet1!B1:B), 
        { Sheet1!B1:B, Sheet1!A1:C }, 
        sequence(1, columns(Sheet1!A1:C), 2), 
        false 
      ), 
      { 2, 3 }, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See the [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12HLROh6H_KC5HlJZPCMS3GjNHAcnSmxBHT1a5QUEnAY/edit#gid=333274696) tab.

Answer (score 0):

Added formula to your sheet:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(z,IF(z="",,INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(z,FILTER({Sheet1!A:C},BYROW(Sheet1!B:B,LAMBDA(Σ,COUNTIF(Sheet1!B1:Σ,Σ)))=1),{2,3},))))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: It works, but I ran into an issue where there is a calculation limit. But thanks for showing me that there's levels to sheets!